# Any idea why my class takes much more memory than it is supposed to?

Tags: java, oop, optimization, memory-management, heap-memory

I am trying to create a class that will act as a X dimension ArrayList that will contain outputs for my X dimension function.
The class works fine but the memory consuption is much higher than it should be, therefore i cannot use it for too many values in too high dimension.

I thought about changing from double to float but I am not allowed to use floats for this project.

```
public ArrayList<XDimensionArray> inception = new ArrayList<XDimensionArray>();

public ArrayList<Double> HistoricInputs= new ArrayList<Double>();
public ArrayList<Double> inputs = new ArrayList<Double>();
public ArrayList<Double> outputs= new ArrayList<Double>();
private int dimensionCourante;
private int dimensionMax;

public XDimensionArray(ArrayList<Pair> Tab_Limites,int _dimensionCourante,int precision,ArrayList<Double> _HistoricInputs)
{
    HistoricInputs = _HistoricInputs;
    dimensionCourante = _dimensionCourante;
    dimensionMax = Tab_Limites.size();
    for(Double i = Tab_Limites.get(dimensionCourante - 1).min; i < Tab_Limites.get(dimensionCourante - 1).max; i += 1./precision)
    {
        inputs.add(i);
        if (dimensionCourante < dimensionMax)
        {
            ArrayList<Double> temp = new ArrayList<Double>();
            temp.addAll(HistoricInputs);
            temp.add(i);
            inception.add(new XDimensionArray(Tab_Limites,dimensionCourante + 1,precision,temp));
        }
        if (dimensionCourante == dimensionMax)
            outputs.add(SetOutput(i));
    }
}
```

Explaination of the code : You call the class giving it

- an array of min/max tubles which repreent the axis, from the size of that array the class guesses the max dimension.
- The current dimension to generate (first call is always 1)
- the precision which represents how many points will be created per unit of the axis (on axis -5;5 with precision 10 we get 100 points with 0.1 between each)
  -The historic of inputs which lets us know who are the parents of the Xdimension array when we are in a lower dimension (basicaly when you are in a 6th dimension XdimArray you know which XdimArrays are your parents "Xdim[0][8][4][2][10]" for example.

For every point we want to create in our axis,

-if this is not the lowest dimension, we fill our XdimensionArray array with new objects of one dimension lower

-if this is the lowest dimension, we finaly fill the output array.

Running the program for 100 values per axis and 4 axis would mean 100^4 values (double) which should use 100Mo of memory right? but my program eats up all the memory i gave him (2.2Go) and it's still not enough.

100 Values in 3 dimensions should mean 10^6 doubles = 1Mo
The program actually uses 500Mo (at least it's able to run)

EDIT : I tried following what happens in 4 dimensions with 100 values per axis. The program creates the first 1rst dimension aray, then 26 out of 100 2nd dimension arrays (and all their 3rd and 4rst dim arrays) then all 2Go are taken and the program stalls

Comment: Welcome to SO! How did you measure memory usage? "my program eats up all the memory I gave him and it's still not enough" - do you get OutOfMemoryError?

Comment: I just used the task manager. Also the error i got was something about Heap memory, althrough i don't know how i got it, now the program just stalls when i run it instead of returning an error

Comment: Task manager can be deceiving, it shows how much memory was assigned to the JVM process, it doesn't mean that the memory is actually used. Did you try running the app with some flags? Setting `-Xmx2g` might help if you have insufficient max heap size.

Comment: I did run -Xms1024M -Xmx2304M settings in my eclipse client. I mean i know there is not enough memory to create the array since the program never finishes creating it and the memory taken by the process remains stagnant at some point.

Answer (score 1):

100<sup>4</sup> is indeed 100 million. 100 million entries in your list, not 100 million bytes.

A `double` is 8 bytes of memory. But you don't use `double`, you use `java.lang.Double`, which is an object, not a primitive value. I believe that an object header is 16 bytes, so that makes 16+8 is 24 bytes.

And your ArrayList contains an array of references of 4 to 8 bytes for each DOuble (depending on whether you have a 32 bit or 64 bit VM and whether you use compressed pointers), so each double takes 28-32 bytes.

Which means you need 2.8Gb (SI units) to 3.2Gb of memory.

Comment: Thanks for your Answer! It seems i must use java.lang.Double to make my ArrayLists. Do you have idea of how i could proceed to maybe use the primitive type or another idea to reduce that memory usage? (i am very new with that problem of memory usage so i never thought about it before when programing) Also, still 3.2Gb of memory is only about 400Mo, my program uses over 2Go

Comment: You could use an array of `double` (`double[]`) instead of a `ArrayList<Double>`